# Custom control binding setter not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control with following code:

```
public partial class TableSelectorControl : UserControl
{
    private Brush _cellHoverBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CadetBlue) { Opacity = 0.3 };

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveSelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveSelection", typeof(TableSelectorSelection),
            typeof(TableSelectorControl));

    public TableSelectorSelection ActiveSelection
    {
        get => (TableSelectorSelection)GetValue(ActiveSelectionProperty);
        set 
        {
            SetValue(ActiveSelectionProperty, value);
            _cellHoverBrush = value.HoverBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set `_cellHoverBrush` on each `ActiveSelectionProperty` update, which is done from ViewModel. Binding works well and the `ActiveSelectionProperty` seemes to change, but the setter is not firing. I surely can use a `FrameworkProperyMetadata`, but I don't want `_cellHoverBrush` to become `static`, the idea is to change it with respect to selected `ActiveSelection`. How can I achieve this?

I can provide more info, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of properties in WPF: .NET Framework properties and dependency properties (which are specific for WPF). Each dependency property has associated a .Net Framework property, but this property is only a wrapper over WPF dependencies properties. This is done to standardize the way we work with properties in WPF. When a dependency property is used in bindings from .xaml files, the WPF framework will not use the .Net wrapper property to get or set the value. This is why, it's not indicated to use other code than `GetValue` and `SetValue` in your .NET wrapper property.

For what you need, you should use **PropertyChangedCallback**, like in the example below:

```
public partial class TableSelectorControl : UserControl
{
    private Brush _cellHoverBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CadetBlue) { Opacity = 0.3 };

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveSelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveSelection", typeof(TableSelectorSelection),
            typeof(TableSelectorControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnActiveSelectionChanged)));

    public TableSelectorSelection ActiveSelection
    {
        get => (TableSelectorSelection)GetValue(ActiveSelectionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ActiveSelectionProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnActiveSelectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tableSelCtrl = d as TableSelectorControl;
        if (tableSelCtrl != null)
        {
            tableSelCtrl._cellHoverBrush = (e.NewValue as TableSelectorSelection)?.HoverBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the PropertyChangedCallback of FrameworkPropertyMetadata doesn't necessarily mean you need to make your field static. Your handler method will get a reference to the instance that is invoking it which you can then modify - you will need to cast it to your type first though.

The PropertyChanged walkthrough on this page shows one way you might do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation